# Check if XElement(Record) exists?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

How can I check if `XElement` has Record & INVID attributes ?
My function returns only single XElement. i.e,

```
<INVENTORY>
  <Record>
    <INVID>1315</INVID>
    <INVNAME>TEST LOCATIONTEST</INVNAME>
    <HOSPNAME>TEST LOCATION</HOSPNAME>
    <INVTYPE>CLINICAL</INVTYPE>
    <INVDT>2013-09-30T09:30:00</INVDT>
    <INVDEF>YES</INVDEF>
    <INVACT>YES</INVACT>
    <UPDDTTM />
    <UPDUSR />
    <ENBREF>true</ENBREF>
    <INVPWD>101315</INVPWD>
  </Record>
</INVENTORY>


XElement xInventory = GetDefaultInventory();        
bool hasInventory = xInventory.Elements("INVID").Any();  //What to do here ? 

if (hasInventory)
{  
    //TO DO Some action 
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to check that inventory element has `Record` element with `INVID` child element, then you can use XPath:

```
XElement inventory = GetDefaultInventory();
XElement invid = inventory.XPathSelectElement("Record/INVID");
if (invid == null) 
    // not exist
```

Or LINQ way:

```
bool exists = inventory.Elements("Record").Elements("INVID").Any();
```

Comment: I tried with LINQ , working fine ! Thanks you @Sergey Berezovskiy

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
bool hasInventory = xInventory.Elements("Record").Any() && xInventory.Descendants("INVID").Any();
```

That will check if `xInventory` element has direct child `Record`, and if it has then check if `xInventory` has child element `INVID`.